# Two Predefined Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, between

If I want to search records based on the previous month's stats how would I do that? So, if I want a report on June 15th, it would include May 15-June 14. A report for July 15th would include June 15-July 14 and so on. As of now I have this:

```
where currentemploydate between CAST('2013/05/15' AS DATETIME) AND CAST('2013/06/14' AS DATETIME)
```

but then I don't know how to auto update the dates for next month.  If the report is ran on the 20th, it still shows the dates from the 14th of the current month back to the 15th of the previous month

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: SQL SERVER MGMT STUDIOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then I think you want:

```
where currentemploydate between CAST('2013-05-15' AS DATETIME) AND
                                dateadd(month, 1, CAST('2013-05-15' AS DATETIME) )
```

This should work for any date constant.

Comment: Is there a way to make it automatically do that without having to manually enter the months each month? So when I run the report it automatically pulls the data based on that time period, not by having to go in and edit the query each time

Comment: @user3630473 . . . This may be another question.  I don't understand what month range you want when you someone just "runs" the report.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @START datetime
SET @START = '2012-07-31'
DECLARE @END datetime
SET @END = DATEADD(DAY, 30, @START)
select @START, @END
```

Assuming a month is 30 days though....is that an acceptable assumption?